# Codeigniter Pass the serial number of current image

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I have retrieved a array from my database. I need to pass the current number (Serial number) of image into the view so that I can display it in there.

Say, in the first page, I need to pass `#1` so that it would let the user know that it is the first image. And say if they are visiting the 3rd image (`array[2]`) then it should display `#3` .

Basically what I have is the option for the users to click `next #4` and `#2 previous` to go through the images and I want to display the serial number of the current image in the page.

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#21 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "17"
    ["gallery_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "sample"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(12) "n9a67681.jpg"
    ["description"]=>
    string(10) "sdhdfhafdj"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2013-06-29 08:25:56"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#22 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "18"
    ["gallery_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "sample"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(13) "n9a676811.jpg"
    ["description"]=>
    string(10) "sdhdfhafdj"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2013-06-29 08:26:28"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#23 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "19"
    ["gallery_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "sample"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(13) "n9a676812.jpg"
    ["description"]=>
    string(10) "sdhdfhafdj"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2013-06-29 08:27:04"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#24 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["gallery_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "safdhfh"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(35) "tumblr_mfyn3l81ft1qkfae2o1_1280.jpg"
    ["description"]=>
    string(4) "dsgd"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2013-06-29 08:28:16"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#25 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "21"
    ["gallery_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) "dshfdhsd"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(36) "tumblr_mfyn3l81ft1qkfae2o1_12801.jpg"
    ["description"]=>
    string(6) "dahadf"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2013-06-29 08:29:35"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that pagination class could help you: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = example.com/controller/action/uri_segment;
$config['total_rows'] = 5;
$config['per_page'] = 1;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$position = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$data['image'] = your_array[$position];

$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

Put in your view file "echo $links" (to create the next and previous link), and work as you want with your image informations.